# Writing different experiment output run to different cells in a sheet (Excel file)

Tags: anylogic

I am simultaneously running a model with different input values and it is producing different output on each run. I am trying to create a code that will get anylogic to wright each experiment output run in a different cell in excel sheet i.e. throughput Vs. Time. I am using dataset. Wondering If there is any script or hint can help in solving the issue?

Currently I am using the following commands. They keep overwriting the output using the same cells.

```
Out_excelFile1.setCellValue("Sink1 Out",2,2,2);
```

Out_excelFile1.writeDataSet(Sink1_D,2,3,2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best if you actually use the build-in database for outputs and only write to Excel at the end of all runs, tbh.

But in your case, you need to change the row number by your replication/iteration number. Use `getCurrentIteration()` or `getCurrentReplication()` in your "after simulation run" or "after replication" or "after iteration" experiment code sections to get this right.

Then, it would look something like `Out_excelFile1.setCellValue("Sink1 Out",2,getCurrentIteration(),2);`

(Details depend on your actual implementation, check the help for further info on replications, iterations and those functions)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am currently looking into Anylogic help document for the Iteration topic. Regarding getCurrentIteration, I am facing the following error Description: The method getCurrentIteration() is undefined for the type Main. Location: LOR_Smart_Wall10/Main/level/button - Button. I have tried the code in the main destroy the window. It didn't work. How can I define getCurrentIteration in main?

Comment: `((ExperimentParamVariation) getExperiment()).getCurrentIteration()` or similar. The iteration is fundamentally a property of the experiment, not the model and only exists for multi-run experiment types.

Comment: You need to understand Java inheritance really to understand the syntax but more correctly you could use something like `(getExperiment() instanceof ExperimentMultipleRuns) ? ((ExperimentMultipleRuns) getExperiment()).getCurrentIteration : 1`. This returns 1 if it isn't a multi-run experiment running the model and the iteration number if it is.

Comment: But note that this seems bad design: if you're writing outputs for multiple runs this code should be in the actions of the experiment not within the model. The model could also have the iteration number passed to it by the experiment (as a model parameter) if you do want the model to 'know' that it's part of a multi-run experiment and structure output data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. I have created parameter variation experiment where I added the code Out_excelFile1.setCellValue("Sink1 Out",2,getCurrentIteration(),2); in Java action, After Iteration (descried by Benjamin) . When running the main, does the parameter variation experiment run in the background or I need to run it separately?

Comment: I slightly disagree with with using the database until the end.  I agree with not pushing to Excel until the end, but constant read/writes to the database can cause performance issues.  I tend to hold the data in other variable structures - even possibly create a class to just record data for each iteration, and then loop to write that to Excel as needed.  I find the syntax a little easier too, as there is not querying of the DB & everything is just foundational Java.

Comment: Fair enough @AmyBrownGreer. But I never have problems with dbase performance (not working with big data) and actually find the SQL syntax easier :) Great we have all options :D